How to create touch ScrollViewer for datagrid
How can i create for datagrid touch scroolviewer when i`m turn off tablet mode?
<runtime>
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport=true" /></runtime>

